# GridView SelectionMode with maximum 2 selections in Windows 8 Apps

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I would like to maximize the item selections in a Gridview, so that the user should select 1 or 2 items. In XAML there are only predefined options in `SelectionMode` like `Multiple`, `Extended`, `Single`, `None`. I'm afraid I need another way to maximize the selections. Could you give me a suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to mimic maximum 2 selection is to subscibe on the [SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged.aspx) event and remove the first/last element from the [SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.selecteditems.aspx) collection:

XAML:

```
<GridView SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectionChanged="GridView_SelectionChanged" />
```

Codebehind:

```
private void GridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var gridView = sender as GridView;
    if (gridView == null) return;
    if (gridView.SelectedItems.Count > 2)
    {
        gridView.SelectedItems.Remove(gridView.SelectedItems[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, great answer. I'd probably remove the oldest one. If you want to encapsulate this ability you could make your own control that inherits from GridView and add a DependencyProperty for MaxSelectionCount.